# Graph traversal and filtering in indoor navigation and path finding

Tags: java, navigation, filtering, path-finding, graph-traversal

Which of the following options take less processing time/is less expensive in a graph traversal algorithm for a (indoor) navigation system?

1. To produce all possible paths between start and destination points (nodes on the graph) then applying a filtering mechanism to match the navigation user's capabilities and preferences (such as finding all the paths on the graph and then exclude stairways for wheelchair users), or
2. As soon as the user's profile is available to the system, filter the graph and exclude the paths which are non-traversable for this user and then run a shortest path algorithm?

Comment: [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) may be a better venue for this.  And the answers are probably dependent upon what languages/frameworks/data structures are used.

Comment: I will be using the floor plans to produce the graph and implement with java.

Comment: If you demonstrate examples of the algorithms you've tried to solve the problem using both approaches, you are more likely to get helpful responses.  In light of your comment, the composition, complexity and size of the objects that represent your floor plan and graph concepts are important to understand.  This site may not be the best forum for your question since it is geared toward more specific questions.

Comment: I followed your link and asked here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221305/graph-traversal-and-filtering-in-indoor-navigation-and-path-finding,
if you want to know more details, maybe you could read my answers there and help me with some ideas please?